# Get Hierarchy level and all node references on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have been reading about `CONNECT BY` and CTE in Oracle, but I can't come up with a solution. I don't know how to use properly `CONNECT BY` to my needs, and recursive CTE's in Oracle are limited to 2 branches(one `UNION ALL`) and I'm using 3 branches.

In SQL Server it was kind of easy after I found this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/). I only added another `UNION ALL` regarding to return all node references.

What I trying to do is having a hierarchy like this:

```
Code|Father
1   |NULL
2   |1
3   |2
```

And this should return me:

```
Node|Father|Level|JumpsToFather
1   |1     |1    |0
2   |1     |2    |1
2   |2     |2    |0
3   |1     |3    |2
3   |2     |3    |1
3   |3     |3    |0
```

Note: Yes I need to return a reference to themselves counting as zero jumps on the hierarchy

Comment: CTE's in Oracle are not limited to 2 branches in `union` or `union all`. **Recursive** CTE's are limited that way, but presumably that is not what you meant, since recursive CTE's are only available in Oracle since version 11 release 2, and you are on Oracle 10. However, for a general solution you **would** need recursive CTE, so it's not clear what you really want. A solution that only works for at most 3 levels? It would also help to show in what format you have the inputs in your problem.

Comment: @mathguy True. TBH, I'm OK if I need to say I only have a solution for Oracle 11 R2. I edited the question to best address how the data is stored in the table and correct the term to mention recursives CTEs.

Comment: OK, found the correct solution using hierarchical queries. I will add it to my answer. You may want to test both solutions to see which is faster; from some experiments (with a different setup) recursive CTE was quite a bit faster than hierarchical query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a recursive CTE. I used `lvl` as column header since `level` is a reserved word in Oracle. You will see other differences in terminology as well. I use "parent" for the immediately higher level and "ancestor" for >= 0 steps (to accommodate your requirement of showing a node as its own ancestor). I used an `ORDER BY` clause to cause the output to match yours; you may or may not need the rows ordered.

Your question stimulated me to read again, in more detail, about hierarchical queries, to see if this can be done with them instead of recursive CTEs. Actually I already know you can, by using `CONNECT_BY_PATH`, but using a `substr` on that just to retrieve the top level in a hierarchical path is not satisfying at all, there must be a better way. (If that was the only way to do it with hierarchical queries, I would definitely go the recursive CTE route if it was available). I will add the hierarchical query solution here, if I can find a good one.

```
with h (      node, parent ) as (
       select 1   , null  from dual union all
       select 2   , 1     from dual union all
       select 3   , 2     from dual
     ),
     r (      node  , ancestor, steps ) as (
       select node  , node    , 0    
       from   h
       union all
       select r.node, h.parent, steps + 1
       from   h join r
                on h.node = r.ancestor
     ) 
select   node, ancestor, 
         1+ (max(steps) over (partition by node)) as lvl, steps
from     r
where    ancestor is not null
order by lvl, steps desc;


      NODE   ANCESTOR        LVL      STEPS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0
         2          1          2          1
         2          2          2          0
         3          1          3          2
         3          2          3          1
         3          3          3          0
```

**Added**: Hierarchical query solution

OK - found it. Please test both solutions to see which performs better; from tests on a different setup, recursive CTE was quite a bit faster than hierarchical query, but that may depend on the specific situation. ALSO: recursive CTE works only in Oracle 11.2 and above; the hierarchical solution works with older versions.

I added a bit more test data to match Anatoliy's.

```
with h (      node, parent ) as (
       select 1   , null  from dual union all
       select 2   , 1     from dual union all
       select 3   , 2     from dual union all
       select 4   , 2     from dual union all
       select 5   , 4     from dual
     )
select                                             node, 
           connect_by_root node                 as ancestor, 
           max(level) over (partition by node)  as lvl,
           level - 1                            as steps
from       h
connect by parent = prior node
order by   node, ancestor;



      NODE   ANCESTOR        LVL      STEPS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0
         2          1          2          1
         2          2          2          0
         3          1          3          2
         3          2          3          1
         3          3          3          0
         4          1          3          2
         4          2          3          1
         4          4          3          0
         5          1          4          3
         5          2          4          2
         5          4          4          1
         5          5          4          0
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! And about the terminologies, I'm totally OK with that, IKR that my English that was actually bad and I named everything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

thx for question, i spent 1 hour to write this:

```
with t as ( select code, parent, level l
              from (select 1 as code, NULL as parent from dual union
                    select 2 , 1 from dual union 
                    select 3 , 2 from dual 
                    -- add some more data for demo case
                    union 
                    select 4 , 2 from dual union 
                    select 5 , 4 from dual 
                    )
              start with parent is null
            connect by prior code = parent )

select code, (select code 
                from t t1 
               where l = ll 
                 and rownum = 1
                start with t1.code = main_t.code
               connect by prior t1.parent = t1.code 
                 ) parent, 
       l code_level, 
       jumps
from (
select distinct t.*, l-level jumps, level ll
  from t
 connect by level <= l
 ) main_t
order by code, parent
```

as you can see, i'am add some more data to test my sql, here is output

```
      CODE     PARENT CODE_LEVEL      JUMPS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0
         2          1          2          1
         2          2          2          0
         3          1          3          2
         3          2          3          1
         3          3          3          0
         4          1          3          2
         4          2          3          1
         4          4          3          0
         5          1          4          3
         5          2          4          2
         5          4          4          1
         5          5          4          0

 13 rows selected
```

Comment: Your answer is good and worked too, but I'm accepting the other because of readability. I might check it back to see which performs better.